# How far can I throw a snowball?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A friend and I were playing a game of "snowball wars" today, and it got me thinking - what is the farthest distance one can throw a snowball in Minecraft? (Assuming the target is on the same level as you)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe they act the same as arrows;

> They will fly in a parabola (arc) and will travel approximately 15 blocks when fired parallel to a flat plane. Arrows have a maximum range of around 50 blocks when fired at a 45 degree angle on a flat plane.

Comment: "I believe" or "I guess"? No offence intended, but it's an important difference.

Comment: I know what you mean - I would still say a guess (or in this case, the observation that arrows, eggs, and snowballs all act similarly) is better than nothing at all. Anyway, that's what the votes are for when someone finds the actual truth. :)

Comment: I just tested; you're right. Eggs, arrows, and snowballs all go the same distance.

Comment: Wow, I can throw an egg as hard as I can fire an arrow!

Answer (score 0):

Using TNT, a very long way. Certainly to the edge of your loaded chunks.

Simply amass a pile of TNT, ignite it, and throw the snowball so that it is above the TNT when it ignites. It will be blasted a very long way.